# DefaultTableModel setDataVector appends older rows with new

Tags: java, jtable

I have a JTable and DefaultTableModel at class level.
First time when I initialize the jTable and Model I add 10 rows.
on Button click I get 3 rows from my database so I have to show only these 3 rows by removing earlier 10 rows.
I do this using `tableModel.setDataVector(data, columnNames);`
But the main problem is, the table only replaces 3 old rows with new one and still remaining 7 rows are shown as it is.

Can any one help?

Thanks,
Jai

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood, you want to reconstruct the table with the 3 rows from the database and delete the earlier 10 rows. If that is true then do this,

```
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
   // If the action is for getting data from DB then do,
   DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel) myTable.getModel();
   // int rowCount = dtm.getRowCount();
   /*
     for (int row = rowCount - 1; row >= 0; row--) {
        dtm.removeRow(row); 
   } */
   // or
   if(dtm.getRowCount() > 0) {
     dtm.setRowCount(0);
   }
// Add code to get your 3 rows from the database.
}
```

Comment: +1 for `removeRow()`, but why start at the end? E.g. `while (dtm.getRowCount() > 0) { dtm.removeRow(0); }`

Comment: @trashgod      I haven't tried using this while(), but in this case if we delete from back we are assured that we are taking care of ArrayOutOfBoundException. Since if we start from first row then if we delete one row after another then row count reduces. So we get ArrayOutOfBoundException. I experienced this exception during JTable deletion many times.

Comment: @trashgod and @Amarnath : Thanks for helping friends, but I got a much easier way to achieve it:                                   `tableModel.setRowCount(0);`                                         and then filled the values :                                         
`tableModel.setDataVector(data, columnNames);` - Jai Gharge

Comment: @trashgod       Sure. I have to update my answer. The method he suggested was spot on.